# Installing dependencies of dependencies on the filesystem using pip

Tags: python, pip, package

Let's say I have 3 Python projects, `foo`, `foodep`, and `foodepdep`, all in the same directory on my filesystem. Down the line these will be pushed to a private package index, so in the `install_requires` section of `setup.py` for `foo` I have `"foodep"`, and for `foodep` I have `"foodepdep"`.

Just doing `pip install -e .` will fail because all of these projects are local to my filesystem, not a package index.

I tried using a `requirements.txt` file for `foo` containing `-e ../foodep`, but that tries to use the `install_requires` of `foodep` to get `foodepdep` and fails. Is there some way to keep all of this local to my filesystem while still referencing each package by name in the `install_requires`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tell pip to treat a directory of packages as a package index without generating archives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52728103/tell-pip-to-treat-a-directory-of-packages-as-a-package-index-without-generating)